# Vuex - Shared server side state?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am modifying [hacker-news example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) and I added notifications component (If fetching external data goes wrong: save notification with error in vuex, after user reads it and clicks X remove it from vuex state). Looks like this:

```
[NOTIFY] (state, message) {    
state.data.push(message)    
},

[READ_NOTIFICATION] (state, index) {
state.data.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Problem: When data is being fetched and state is being set on server, it keeps error there in global state forever, which means that if I open new browser I will get the same old error from previous session.

Shouldn't server-side vuex state reset on every request? What am I missing?

Comment: * Moved to answer for formatting *

Comment: If you followed the example, const store = createStore() in app.js is what creates a new store for every request. Where/how are you loading that store?

Answer (score -1):

I'm confused as to what you mean by "server-side state". Vuex is a client side store. What and why are you saving state to the server?

Furthermore, I cannot tell what you are doing with the code? Is that in a store.js file? In the mutations object?

You would need to wrap that in a vue method like so:

In the Vue file:

```
methods: {
  clicksButton (idx) {
    this.$store.commit('read_notification', idx)
  }
}
```

In the store.js file:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    data: [],
    error: null
  },
  mutations: {
    read_notification (state, idx) {
      state.data.splice(idx, 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Vuex is not only used for client side, if you are using server side rendering, it is initialized on the server and passed to the client.